# Series of if statements functioning incorrectly

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a set of if statements that searches the raw hhtml body of an email defined by $html_part, that will replace the email's cid: text `<img src="cid:image001.jpg@1REG5DS">` with a relative hyperlink to the actual image that is being saved.

The problem is, if the html body of the email contains only .jpg images, they are numbered sequentially such as  image001.jpg, image002.jpg, image003.jpg. If theres a .png image first then 2 .jpg images following it, it will become, image001.png, image002.jpg, image003.jpg.
But at the moment i am testing it out with an email with 3 .jpg images only but it replaces all the email's cid parts with the first matched image, instead of sequentially. Now the image it's too be replaced with is in the directory i have a side-script for that, which does this automatically. It extracts all the images from the email and places them in a folder.

What is wrong with the if statements, why are they not replacing accordingly?

```
/***************************** 1st image in email**********************************/
if (preg_match('/cid:([^"@]*).(png|jpg|gif|bmp)@([^"]*)/', $html_part, $m)){

    $find = '/cid:([^"@]*).'.$m[2].'@([^"]*)/';

    if ($m[2] == 'png') $replace = $png1;
    if ($m[2] == 'jpg') $replace = $jpg1;
    if ($m[2] == 'gif') $replace = $gif1;
    if ($m[2] == 'bmp') $replace = $bmp1;

    $html_part = preg_replace($find, $replace, $html_part);
}

if (preg_match('/cid:([^"@]*).(png|jpg|gif|bmp)@([^"]*)/', $html_part, $m)){

    $find = '/cid:([^"@]*).'.$m[2].'@([^"]*)/';

    if ($m[2] == 'png') $replace = $png2;
    if ($m[2] == 'jpg') $replace = $jpg2;
    if ($m[2] == 'gif') $replace = $gif2;
    if ($m[2] == 'bmp') $replace = $bmp2;

    $html_part = preg_replace($find, $replace, $html_part);
}

/***************************** 3rd image in email**********************************/
if (preg_match('/cid:([^"@]*).(png|jpg|gif|bmp)@([^"]*)/', $html_part, $m)){

    $find = '/cid:([^"@]*).'.$m[2].'@([^"]*)/';

    if ($m[2] == 'png') $replace = $png3;
    if ($m[2] == 'jpg') $replace = $jpg3;
    if ($m[2] == 'gif') $replace = $gif3;
    if ($m[2] == 'bmp') $replace = $bmp3;

    $html_part = preg_replace($find, $replace, $html_part);
}
```

Comment: put the less restrictive conditions **first** and continue with the most restrictive ones (maybe your input case is falling within the first condition, because is more restrictive). Also, try using the **if/else** logic (not only ifs), or a **switch/case**

Comment: Could it be that your second (and third) preg_match matches the string you've just replaced in the first (and second) preg_replace ?

Comment: @huelbois That is what i'm thinking as well, and **Kani** i have used the else statements as well and still it produces the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your preg_replace matches ALL instance of $find in $html_part. 
But in $find, you only have the $m[2] part changing, you don't reinject the $m[1] that you've just matched.

Not sure, but you should have something like this (not tested):

```
$find = '/cid:'$m[1].'.'.'.$m[2].'@([^"]*)/';
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I just had to modify your example code:
              
     `$find = '/cid:'.$m[1].'.'.$m[2].'@([^"]*)/';`
You had an extra single quote near the $m[2]

Answer (score 0):

Use instead:

```
if(this is it){

//somecode

}elseif(this is it){

//somecode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is that `preg_replace` replaces ALL matches.  The regex you pass in is searching for all images with the same extension.

What you have:

```
$find = '/cid:([^"@]*).'.$m[2].'@([^"]*)/';

/cid:([^"@]*).jpg@([^"]*)/ - match all jpgs
```

What you want is:

```
$find = '/'.$m[0].'/';

/cid:image001.jpg@1REG5DS/ - match only this jpg file
```